# auto mount usb drives when inserted

Tags: usb, fstab, automount

I have multiple identical USB drives that I want to auto mount at specific points when they are inserted. I added an entry in fstab for each drive with it's UUID:

```
UUID = uniqueUUID1 /mountPath1   exfat   rw,relatime  0 0
UUID = uniqueUUID2 /mountPath2   exfat   rw,relatime 0 0
UUID=uniqueUUID3 /mountPath3 exfat rw,relatime 0 0
```

When I insert one of the USB drives it automounts correctly. However when I insert a second (or subsequent drive) it doesn't auto mount. It detects the additional drives, but doesn't mount them. fdisk-l shows all connected drives and their assigned different nodes (/dev/sdc1,/dev/sdc1,etc...). If I hover over the drives in Files I get the option to "mount and open" the drive. When I click it, the drive mounts to the path set in fstab.

I can mount additional drives through the command line

```
sudo mount UUID=uniqueUUID.
```

All the drives mount as expected, IF they are the only one plugged in. I thought it was maybe just my machine (Ubuntu 20.4). I tried it on another machine running 18.something and got the same result. If I plug in a different brand/kind of usb drive second it mounts correctly.

The mount paths are named by their respective UUID:

```
/home/myDrives/uniqueUUID
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.